# i can't see images in the emails when i insert images in the ckeditor and uploads from fckeditor

Tags: php, email, ckeditor, fckeditor

i need help to sending emails via ckeditor and also facing following problems?

1) problem is that i can't see image when i `echo $message =$editor1;` 
   and how can i see images in the email when i insert images in the ckedit?

ckeditor uploading image on the folder which is `UserFilesAbsolutePath`

2) how do i send multiple receipt emails in the `textarea name='email'`??

**For example multiple receipt emails With Commas**

```
demo@yahoo.com,test@yahoo.com,123@gmail.com & Sending TO All Select
//same like gmail,yahoo & hotmail
```

**Process Page**

**Here My Sending Emails Page**

```
if(isset($_POST['sendemail'])){
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$email=$_POST['email'];
$subject=$_POST['subject']; 
$editor1=$_POST['editor1']; 

$your_email = 'test@yahoo.com'; //CHANGE TO YOUR SETTINGS
$domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; //YOUR DOMAIN AND EXTENSION
$to = $email;
$subject = $subject;
echo $message =$editor1;

$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= "From: Testing Email<$your_email>\r\n" .  
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(); 

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
//if(!empty($message)){
//header('Location:index.php');
//}

}
```

**Index Page**

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
To:
<textarea class="input_field" name="email" id="email"></textarea>

Subject:
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" />

Message:
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1" id="editor1" ></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
tabSpaces:10,
filebrowserBrowseUrl :'ckeditor/filemanager/browser/default/browser.html?Connector=http://localhost/test/phpmultipleemails/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/connector.php',
filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : 'ckeditor/filemanager/browser/default/browser.html?Type=Image&Connector=http://localhost/test/phpmultipleemails/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/connector.php',
filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl :'ckeditor/filemanager/browser/default/browser.html?Type=Flash&Connector=http://localhost/test/phpmultipleemails/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/connector.php',
filebrowserUploadUrl  :'http://localhost/test/phpmultipleemails/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php?Type=File',
filebrowserImageUploadUrl : 'http://localhost/test/phpmultipleemails/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php?Type=Image',
filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : 'http://localhost/test/phpmultipleemails/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php?Type=Flash',
filebrowserWindowWidth : '730',
filebrowserWindowHeight : '500'
});
CKEDITOR.instances["post-content"].on("instanceReady", InstanceReadyEvent);
function InstanceReadyEvent() {
this.document.on("keyup", function () {
$('#editform').trigger('change');
});
}
</script>
```

**Here My UserFilesPath For Ckeditor Filemanager**

```
$Config['UserFilesPath'] = 
'http://localhost/test/phpmultipleemails/uploads/';
```

**Here My UserFilesAbsolutePath For Ckeditor Filemanager**

```
$Config['UserFilesAbsolutePath'] = 
'D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\phpmultipleemails\\uploads\\;
```

Comment: if your sending the email externally ie: to gmail or something it won't be able to open images stored on your localhost so you'd have to upload the images to a publically accessible web server before they appear in your emails.

Comment: @dave i have already stored images in the folder from `ckeditor fckeditor file manager` and also images showing in the folder?

Comment: but ck editor is putting in the image links as `<img src="http://localhost/test/phpmultipleemails/uploads/image.jpg" />` you're then going to gmail or yahoo or wheverever that has no access to your localhost and so it cannot display the email.  If you view the email source you'll see what I mean.  If you download the email to your local mail client the images will appear fine. http://localhost isn't publically available or even a valid domain name. your path needs to be the URL of the site when its on your live server but you need to upload the images onto the live server too before they work

Comment: @dave i just want to echo `$message` if it will work then i will try on the webserver?

Comment: because your url is STILL localhost!

Comment: @dave should i upload it on the webserver ? then it will work? and also what about multiple receipt emails how do i send emails on ultiple receipt emails with `commas`? like hotmail,gmail&yahoo?

Comment: seperate recipients with semi-colon so blah@hotmail.com;blah@yahoo.com;blah@bob.com  If you use a mailcomponent like swiftmailer its easier.

Comment: for images to work in an email they must be linked to a proper web address on a proper webserver ie www.yourdomain.com/phpmultipleemails/uploads/image.jpg and you must store the image files on your web server in that location too otherwise they wont open.  I integrated CKeditor and CKfinder into my CRM application bulk mailer and it worked fine once I got the file path and the web path tied up and on the web server.  Just won't even work on localhost.

Comment: @dave thanks for help let me try after uploaded on the webserver

Answer (score 1):

Google uses a proxy to display images. Since your localhost is not publicly accessible, Google is unable to find the the image you sent in the mail.

Have a look at the `src` attribute of the `img` tag in Gmail. It's something like that: [https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/HMqMF9fRFZZi(...)](https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/HMqMF9fRFZZi%28...%29) and not a localhost URL.

However, you can use a tunnel service such as ngrok to make your localhost publicly accessible: https://ngrok.com/usage